# Weird sign issue with mapping from cartesian to bispherical coordinates

Tags: c#, math, mapping, coordinate-systems

I want to map cartesian coordinates (x,y,z) to bispherical coordinates (sigma,tau,phi) and back accourding to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bispherical_coordinates).

Here are my functions:

```
public static Vector3 ProjectBisphericalToCartesian(Vector3 bispherical, double a)
{
  var sigma = (double)bispherical.X;
  var tau = (double)bispherical.Y;
  var phi = (double)bispherical.Z;
  var d = Math.Cosh(tau) - Math.Cos(sigma);
  var s = a / d;
  var x = s * Math.Sin(sigma) * Math.Cos(phi);
  var y = s * Math.Sin(sigma) * Math.Sin(phi);
  var z = s * Math.Sinh(tau);
  return new Vector3(
      (float)x,
      (float)y,
      (float)z
    );
}

public static Vector3 ProjectCartesianToBispherical(Vector3 cartesian, double a)
{
  var x = (double)cartesian.X;
  var y = (double)cartesian.Y;
  var z = (double)cartesian.Z;
  var R = Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
  var s = R * R + a * a;
  var t = 2.0 * a * z;
  var Q = Math.Sqrt(s * s - t * t);
  var sigma = Math.Acos((R * R - a * a) / Q);
  var tau = Asinh(t / Q);
  var phi = Math.Atan(y / x);
  return new Vector3(
      (float)sigma,
      (float)tau,
      (float)phi
    );
}

// sinh^-1 ("areasinus hyperbolicus")
private static double Asinh(double x)
{
  return Math.Log(x + Math.Sqrt(x * x + 1.0));
}
```

I test the function by generating random numbers for (x,y,z) and a, convert them to bispherical coordinates and back to cartesian and check whether or not they are equal to the original cartesian corrdinates (up to some small tolerance).

It turns out that *some* cartesian coordinates flip the sign of its x and y component (z is okay) while other's do not. For example {X:-5,3434 Y:2,569566 Z:-1,195607} flips the sign of the x and y component while {X:7,586471 Y:-6,154929 Z:1,494778} works fine.

I can not find an error in my code unfortunately.
The issue appears to be caused by negative x values in the original cartesian coordinates which will cause the sign of x and y to be flipped after conversion and back. I just don't see why that happens.

Does anybody have an idea what is going on here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it. Wolfram was mentioning something about half-planes so it occurred to me that using Atan2(y, x) instead of Atan(y/x) could fix the issue and it did.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don’t actually have the answer for you but maybe by putting our heads together we can do it.

First of all it looks to me like you did correctly transcribe the Wikipedia formulas. So what kind of a problem is this? Either the Math functions don’t do exactly the same thing as the functions referenced in Wikipedia, or else there is an error in Wikipedia.

At a guess I would not think that the methods in Math are differently defined.  These functions have been around a long time and are very conventional. Maybe Wikipedia is wrong.

The type of error you have is a sign error. So you should look at what happens when the signs of one or two of the inputs changes. For example if we flip the sign of x then the sign of phi changes (it moves 180 degrees) in the conversion to bispherical. Correspondingly in the conversion to Cartesian, if we flip the sign of phi then the sign of x changes due to the cos(phi).

However if we flip the signs of both x and y then the sign of phi does not change. Neither do the other bispherical calculations change since they only use x and y within squaring. On the other hand if we change the sign of phi in the conversion to Cartesian, the signs of x and y do change. So there are two points in the Cartesian system that map to the same bispherical coordinates, while the two corresponding bisperical coordinates do map back to different Cartesian coordinates. It would seem that you need to introduce a sign in the conversion of x and y to phi. (Or, conceivably a sign in one of the other bispherical coordinates to make up for the lack of sign in phi.)

Comment: About the math function being different I totally agree: I don't see that happening as they are pretty standard.
Also I double-checked with all combinations of +/-1 for (x,y,z) and it swaps the sign of both x and y only if x is negative, regardless of the sign of y or z.
About your idea that 2 points in cartesian coordinates map to the same point in bispherical coordinates I'd think that this should not be the case as it should be a one-to-one mapping (no double covering or anything like that). The bispherical space is orthogonal and contains 3 coordinates as is the cartesian.

Comment: interestingly, having a negative y should have the same sign-changing effect on phi as a negative x. however the error only appears on a negative x and not on a negative y. wtf ?!

Comment: so it is the case that (+1,+1,+1) and (-1,-1,+1) as well as (+1,-1,+1) and (-1,+1,+1) map to the same bispherical coordinates (and therefore can not be distinguished when mapping back).
Now I wonder, if this is an error in wikipedia or if I misunderstood something about the concept of these coordinates as being uniquely mappable into each other.

Comment: I agree it should not be the case that two Cartesian points map to the same bispherical point. What I am saying though is that if you look at the conversion formulas on Wikipedia to go from Cartesian to bisoherical, it looks like those formulas do map two different Cartesian points to the same bispherical point. Specifically if both x and y are positive vs then switch the sign off both of them to negative. In other words the Wikipedia formulas seem to be wrong.

Comment: I would think it is necessary to introduce a sign factor in the Wikipedia formulas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206812/discussion-between-lenny-and-sjb-sjb).